# Add value from other option to a dropdown list

Tags: javascript

I am using a platform called Kintone and am trying to add in custom Javascript in order to allow for there to be a drop-down list of options that has an 'other' option. If the user selects the other option, they can enter in what they want to put into this field and then submit the value and it will then be saved on the drop-down list. Attached below is code pulled from the [help page](https://developer.kintone.io/hc/en-us/articles/115009553188) of Kintone which allows for the other button to pull up a separate text field to store the value that the user wants. I'm thinking that there needs to be some small edit on this in order to allow for the value to be saved in the dropdown list itself instead of in the separate text field. I am not sure if this is a Kintone specific question (I know it's not very commonly used) or if it can be accomplished just with Javascript knowledge (which I largely lack :( ). Thank you in advance for the help!

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var RADIOBUTTON = "allergies";
var MULTICHOICE = "cause";
var TEXTFIELD = "other";
var RADIO_VALUE = "Yes";
var MULTI_VALUE = "Other";

//Events for detail, create and edit pages
var events = ['app.record.detail.show',
              'app.record.create.show',
              'app.record.create.change.' + RADIOBUTTON,
              'app.record.create.change.' + MULTICHOICE,
              'app.record.create.change.' + TEXTFIELD,
              'app.record.edit.show',
              'app.record.edit.change.' + RADIOBUTTON,
              'app.record.edit.change.' + MULTICHOICE,
              'app.record.edit.change.' + TEXTFIELD];

kintone.events.on(events, function(event) {

    var record = event.record;

    //Hide/unhide fields depending on field choices
    if (record[RADIOBUTTON]['value'] === RADIO_VALUE) {
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(MULTICHOICE, true);

        //If "Other" is not selected for the allergy cause, don't show a text field
        var fieldValue = record[MULTICHOICE]['value'];
        if (fieldValue.length === 0) {
            kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, false);
        }

        //If "Other" is selected for the allergy cause, show a text field
        for (var i = 0; i < fieldValue.length; i++) {
            if (fieldValue[i] === MULTI_VALUE) {
                kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, true);
            }else {
                kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, false);
            }
        }
    }else {
        // If "No" is slected for "Do you have any food or drug allergies?", hide other fields
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(MULTICHOICE, false);
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, false);
    }
});
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot set a value that is not in the choice of the "drop-down" field in "Kintone".

You can add a choice in the dropdown field by using the API, by changing the field settings.

I think this article below is something similart to what you can do to change the setting of the field.

▼　Add Form Fields

https://developer.kintone.io/hc/en-us/articles/115005506868-Add-Form-Fields

To change the settings in the Dropdown field itself, when you open other records, you will also see the choices you added in the above API.

Please note that you cannot add choices to specific records only.

Thanks

Junko

Comment: Note that to initiate the Add Form Fields API, the API initiator needs the Management permissions of the App - basically if they have no control to change settings within the App, they will not be able to use the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish it with the following sample code. I use [kintone UI Component](https://github.com/kintone/kintone-ui-component)
for dropdown and [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#uniq)  to get distinct values for the "other" text field.
You just need to add a space field in the above sample kintone app to display the dropdown and one single line field to save the selected value of the dropdown.
What the code does is to get all distinct values of the "other" field and add these items in the dropdown. 
Also, you can use MultipleChoice control with a little tweak.

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var RADIOBUTTON = "allergies";
    var TEXTFIELD = "other";
    var RADIO_VALUE = "Yes";
    var DROPDWON_VALUE = "Other";
    var CHOICE = "choice";

    // kintone UI Component constructor
    var dropdown = new kintoneUIComponent.Dropdown({
        items: [
                {
                    label: 'Drugs',
                    value: 'Drugs'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Food',
                    value: 'Food'
                }
        ]
    });
    var body = {
        'app': kintone.app.getId(),
        'fields': [TEXTFIELD],
        'query': TEXTFIELD + ' != "" order by $id asc limit 500'
    };
    kintone.api(kintone.api.url('/k/v1/records', true), 'GET', body, function(resp) {
        // success
        var records = resp.records;
        var other = [];
        var items = dropdown.getItems();

        records.forEach(function(rcd) {
            other.push(rcd[TEXTFIELD]['value']);
        });
        var unique = _.uniq(other);
        unique.forEach(function(cause) {
            items.push({label: cause, value: cause});
        });
        items.push({label: DROPDWON_VALUE, value: DROPDWON_VALUE});
        dropdown.setItems(items);
    }, function(error) {
    // error
        console.log(error);
    });

    dropdown.hide();
    var showHideTextField = function(record) {

        //Hide/unhide fields depending on field choices
        if (record[RADIOBUTTON]['value'] === RADIO_VALUE) {
            dropdown.show();
            var show = false;
            var selected_value = dropdown.getValue();

            if (selected_value === DROPDWON_VALUE) {
                show = true;
            }
            kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, show);
        } else {
            dropdown.hide();
            kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, false);
        }
    };
    var setDropdownValues = function(record) {
        var selected_value = record[CHOICE]['value'];
        dropdown.setValue(selected_value);
    };

    //Detail Event
    kintone.events.on('app.record.detail.show', function(event) {
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(CHOICE, true);
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, false);
        dropdown.hide();
    });
    //Create/Edit Events
    kintone.events.on(['app.record.create.show', 'app.record.edit.show'], function(event) {
        if (event.type === 'app.record.edit.show') {
            setDropdownValues(event.record);
        }
        showHideTextField(event.record);
        kintone.app.record.getSpaceElement('cause').appendChild(dropdown.render());
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(CHOICE, false);
        dropdown.on('change', function(value) {
            var show = false;
            var selected_value = dropdown.getValue();
            if (selected_value === DROPDWON_VALUE) {
                show = true;
            }
            var rcrd = kintone.app.record.get();
            rcrd.record[CHOICE]['value'] = selected_value;

            kintone.app.record.set(rcrd);
            //If "Other" is selected for the allergy cause, show a text field
            //If "Other" is not selected for the allergy cause, don't show a text field
            kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, show);
        });
    });
    //Change Events
    kintone.events.on(['app.record.create.change.' + RADIOBUTTON, 'app.record.edit.change.' + RADIOBUTTON], function(event) {
        showHideTextField(event.record);
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(CHOICE, false);
        dropdown.on('change', function(value) {
            var show = false;
            var selected_value = dropdown.getValue();
            if (selected_value === DROPDWON_VALUE) {
                show = true;
            }
            var rcrd = kintone.app.record.get();
            rcrd.record[CHOICE]['value'] = selected_value;

            kintone.app.record.set(rcrd);
            //If "Other" is selected for the allergy cause, show a text field
            //If "Other" is not selected for the allergy cause, don't show a text field
            kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(TEXTFIELD, show);
        });
    });
    //Submit Events
    kintone.events.on(['app.record.create.submit', 'app.record.edit.submit'], function(event) {
        var selected_value = dropdown.getValue();
        if (selected_value === DROPDWON_VALUE) {
            event.record[CHOICE]['value'] = event.record[TEXTFIELD]['value'];
        }
        kintone.app.record.setFieldShown(CHOICE, false);
        return event;
    });
})();
```

[Medical Questionnaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDYWb.png)